# how calculate: mean, standard deviation , coefficient for each ip ping , traceroute

Tags: python, networking, ping, traceroute

1. The code reads a list of IP addresses from a file named `bbb.txt`.
2. It initializes an Excel workbook and worksheets for storing the results.
3. It iterates over each IP address and performs the trace route operation multiple times (specified by the `count` variable).
4. The trace route output is parsed to extract the hop counts.
5. The average hop count is calculated for each trace route iteration.
6. The average hop counts are written to an Excel worksheet named `Average.xlsx`.
7. The average hop counts are also saved to a file named `ip_average.txt`.
8. The average hop counts are read from the file.
9. Another Excel worksheet named `Dataset.xlsx` is created to store the IP addresses and their average hop counts.
10. The average hop counts are written to the worksheet.
11. The mean and threshold values are calculated based on the average hop counts.
12. The standard deviation and coefficient values are calculated.
13. The `after` array is populated based on the threshold.
14. The mean, standard deviation, coefficient, and threshold values are printed.

Please note that this code assumes the availability of the `xlsxwriter` library for writing to Excel files, and the `tracert` command for performing the trace route operation. You may need to install these dependencies before running the code. Additionally, make sure to update the file paths in the code to match the locations of your input and output files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import os
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import os
import statistics
import subprocess
import re
import os

Comment: workbook2 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Dataset.xlsx')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Average.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet1 = workbook2.add_worksheet()

Comment: average_hop_counts = []

unreachable_destination = False
no_hop_counts = False

try:
    with open("C:\\Users\\ALFA\\Downloads\\Desktop\\New folder\\bbb.txt") as file:
        Ip_trace = file.read().splitlines()

    for ip in Ip_trace:
        count = 2  # Set count to 2 for each IP trace
        for j2 in range(count):

Comment: print('Trace for IP:', ip, 'Iteration:', j2 + 1)
            command = f"tracert {ip}"
            try:
                process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                output, error = process.communicate()

                if output:
                    output = output.decode()
                    print(output)

Comment: else:
                    print("No output received.")
                    no_hop_counts = True  # Set the flag indicating no hop counts found
                    continue  # Skip the current iteration and continue with the next iteration

                lines = output.splitlines()
                hop_counts = []

                for line in lines:
                    if line.startswith("  "):
                        hop_count = line.split()[0]
                        try:

Comment: try:
                            hop_counts.append(int(hop_count))
                        except ValueError:
                            pass

                if "Destination net unreachable" in output:
                    unreachable_destination = True  # Set the flag indicating destination is unreachable
                    break  # Break out of the inner loop

Comment: if not hop_counts:
                    no_hop_counts = True  # Set the flag indicating no hop counts found
                    break  # Break out of the inner loop

                # Extract hop counts using regular expressions
                hop_counts = re.findall(r"\d+\s+([\d.]+)\s+ms", output)

Comment: # Convert hop counts to integers
                hop_counts = [int(count) for count in hop_counts]

                average_hop_count = sum(hop_counts) / len(hop_counts)
                average_hop_counts.append(average_hop_count)  # Add this line to populate the list
                print("Average hop count:", average_hop_count)

Comment: except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print(f"Error executing traceroute command: {e}")
                continue  # Skip the current iteration and continue with the next iteration

    if unreachable_destination:
        # Handle the case of unreachable destination
        result_variable = None
    elif no_hop_counts:

Comment: # Handle the case of no hop counts found
        result_variable = None
    #else:
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error executing traceroute command: {e}")
    result_variable = None  # Set result_variable to None if an error occurs

# Write average hop counts to file
with open("C:\\Users\\ALFA\\Downloads\\Desktop\\New folder\\ip_average.txt", 'w') as f:
    for hop_count in average_hop_counts:
        f.write(f"{int(hop_count)}\n")

print("Average hop counts saved to 'ip_average.txt'.")

Comment: # read from file to find Result array
with open("C:\\Users\\ALFA\\Downloads\\Desktop\\New folder\\ip_average.txt") as file2:
    IP_Average = file2.read()
    IP_Average = IP_Average.splitlines()

row = len(Ip_trace)
col = row
c2 = count + 1
Result = [[0 for i in range(col)] for j in range(c2)]
sum1 = [0 for i in range(col)]
mean = [0 for i in range(col)]
std_dev = [0 for i in range(col)]
after = [[0 for i in range(col)] for j in range(c2)]

Comment: # Write the result array to Excel
for i in range(row):
    worksheet.write(0, i, Ip_trace[i])  # Add header representing IP
    j1 = 0
    for j2 in range(col):
        for j in range(1, c2):

Comment: # Assign to result array
            Result[0][i] = Ip_trace[i]
            if j1 < len(IP_Average):  # Check if index is within range
                Result[j][j2] = IP_Average[j1]
                worksheet.write(j, j2, Result[j][j2])  # Write to Excel the average
                j1 += 1
workbook.close()

Comment: # this step to find array content 0 or 1
for j in range(col):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, c2):

        value = Result[i][j]
        if value != '':
            try:
                sum += int(value)  # Convert the value to an integer and sum it
            except ValueError:
                pass  # Ignore non-convertible values

Comment: sum1[j] = sum
    mean[j] = sum1[j] / count

print(sum1, "   ")
print(mean)

s=0
for j1 in range(col):
        s+=mean[j1]
        #thresold=s/len(Ip_ping)
        total_mean = s / len(Ip_trace)  # Calculate the total mean

Comment: # Calculate standard deviation for each average value
std_deviation_values = np.std(mean)

# Calculate coefficient without normalization
if np.mean(mean) != 0 and not np.isnan(np.mean(mean)):
    coefficient_values = std_deviation_values / np.mean(mean)
else:
    coefficient_values = None  # Set coefficient_values to None or handle the case when the mean is zero or NaN

threshold = coefficient_values

Comment: # Assign values to 'after1' based on the threshold
for i in range(1, c2):
    for j in range(col):
        if Result[i][j] != '':
            if threshold > int(Result[i][j]):
                after[i][j] = 1
            if threshold < int(Result[i][j]):
                after[i][j] = 0

print("Threshold:", threshold)

Comment: # Print mean, standard deviation, and coefficient for each IP
for i, ip in enumerate(Ip_trace):
    print("IP:", ip)
    print("total_mean:", total_mean)
    print("Standard Deviation:", std_deviation_values)
    print(" Coefficient Values:", coefficient_values)

Comment: # Write 'after1' to Excel worksheet
for i in range(1, c2):
    for j in range(col):
        print(after[i][j], end="      ")
    print("\n")
    #n = 0
for i in range(0, row):
    worksheet1.write(0, (i), Ip_trace[i])  # add header represent ip
for i in range(1, c2):
    for j in range(col):
        worksheet1.write(i, j, after[i][j])  # wite to excel the average

workbook2.close()